# Доступ к MongoDB чероз MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

Я создал VPS на DigitalOcean (Ubuntu), загрузил на него MongoDB, база существует и работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, когда я пытаюсь подключиться к IP-адресу моего сервера, с нужным портом, MongoDB Compass пишет, что не удается подключение (пробовал и без логин-пароля). Может я что-то еще не настроил?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В файле my.cnf какой bind-addres?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov а не могли бы вы подсказать локацию этого файла? Просто я только недавно с Linux работаю..

Comment: Попробуйте найти папку конфигов `ls /etc | grep mongo` или `ls /etc | grep mysql`. В этой папке должен быть этот файл.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov 
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

Стоит поменять на адрес сервера, я правильно понимаю? Если да, то нужны ли еще доп. настройки?

Comment: Да, попробуйте сперва поменять на 0.0.0.0, если не заработает, то на внешний адрес сервера.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov огромное спасибо, все заработало. Причем при указании внешнего адреса все равно нельзя было достучаться, только по 0.0.0.0

Comment: Вероятно, через некоторое время вы сможете наблюдать в логах mysql/mariadb, как с китайских IP пытаются подобрать пароль. Поэтому сделайте пароль длинным/сложным. А вообще, ограничьте доступ с вашей подсети. Потому что китайцы могут не тупо пароли проверять, а те, которые удалось получить с заранее (при производстве) взломанной материнки.